# In OpenTelemetry, what happens when we use @Trace in a java code?

Tags: java, open-telemetry

[@Trace annotation code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvMm8.png)

This is a method implemented inside a decorator class.
I want to understand what happens with the @Trace annotation.
Any help?

Comment: you need take a look where @Trace comes from then just google it ?

Comment: Which dependency is the @Trace annotation coming from? Many variations of that annotation that have been published over the years. See these docs for annotations provided by opentelemetry: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/annotations/